# imask.js pads zeros at end different than the length of scale

Tags: masking, input-mask, imaskjs

In price mask (imask.js) I use this:

```
{
   mask: Number,
   signed: true,
   scale: 3,
   normalizeZeros: true,
   padFractionalZeros: true,
   ...
}
```

This adds max 3 extra zeroes at the end, because the scale is 3. I want to be abble to add max 2, while the scale is 3.

The scale should be **3**, but the added extra zeros at the end should be **max 2**. How to achieve this?

Example:

```
4 -> 4.00       // extra 2 zeros added
4.5 -> 4.50     // 1 zero added
4.56 -> 4.56    // nothing added
4.50 -> 4.50    // nothing added or removed
4.567 -> 4.567  // nothing added or removed
```

Comment: I don't think it can easily be done as is. I'm considering forking the project to modify `padFractionalZeros` to accept a `number` value, and changing the [function that does the padding](https://github.com/uNmAnNeR/imaskjs/blob/a076513f777467b612b6f3671a5d8e5ab98c2fda/packages/imask/src/masked/number.js#L302-L309)

Comment: Did some quick testing and it seems to work fine. Here are the changes [https://github.com/gabrieljablonski/imaskjs/commit/b5ab3af661c59620e12538c24d4d07f1e2d26dc9](https://github.com/gabrieljablonski/imaskjs/commit/b5ab3af661c59620e12538c24d4d07f1e2d26dc9)